# Reverse a string in-place using recursion

Tags: python

There is a *leetcode* question on recursion. Reverse a string, in place, using recursion. Do not allocate an additional array.

> Write a function that reverses a string. The input string is given as
> an array of characters char[].
>
> Do not allocate extra space for another array, you must do this by
> modifying the input array in-place with O(1) extra memory.
>
> You may assume all the characters consist of printable ASCII
> characters.

My solution doesn't work as my slicing operator is creating a copy of the list, rather than being in place. I can't seem to add a parameter to the function, as the test harness isn't expecting an additional parameter.

How do you do this, without an additional parameter to detect the current position index into the string you are trying to reverse, or without an intermediate data structure you append to through the recursive call?

```
class Solution:
    def reverseString(self, s: List[str]) -> None:
        """
        Do not return anything, modify s in-place instead.
        """
        
        if len(s) <= 1:
            return
        
        temp = s[0]
        s[0] = s[len(s)-1]
        s[len(s)-1] = temp        
        return self.reverseString(s[1:len(s)-1])
```

My function with an input of "hello" returns `["o","e","l","l","h"]`.  This is because the first time the function is called it operates on the list in place, and subsequent calls are achieved through a slice of the string.

Comment: Why not give your desired additional parameter a default value?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. There's a wall there.

Comment: You were right, adding a default parameter let me get it going.  Thanks @superbrain

Comment: Note, however, that the recursion stack takes O(n) extra space, so that doesn't fulfill the requirement anyway.

Comment: @superbrain They are just rehashing the question as a recursion problem in the recursion tutorial.  So the question itself just has a little hint icon saying, try solving with recursion.  I know how to solve it with two pointers non recursively.

Answer (score 0):

From what i understood, the solution should be recursive. Try this:

**EDIT:** (as should look in leetcode)

```py
def reverseStringHelper(s, index):
    length = len(s)
    if index >= length / 2:
        return
    
    temp = s[index]
    s[index] = s[length - 1 - index]
    s[length - 1 - index] = temp
    reverseString(s, index + 1)

def reverseString(s):
    reverseStringHelper(s, 0)
```

Defining `arr = ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l' ,'o']` and calling `reverseString(arr, 0)` will result in `['o', 'l', 'l', 'e', 'h']`

You may call it from a different function so it would only accept the list.

Comment: The issue was I couldn't work out how to add a parameter to the function without leetcode test harness complaining.  I added a default parameter thanks to @superbrain

Comment: To do that i usually fill in the given default function with a call to a helper function that accepts whatever you need (just as i wrote in my answer).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all.  The solution was to add a parameter with a default, to get over the issues with the leetcode test harness, so now I can do it as below:

```
   class Solution:
    def reverseString(self, s: List[str], start = 0) -> None:
        """
        Do not return anything, modify s in-place instead.
        """
        if len(s[start:len(s)-start]) <= 1:
            return
        
        end = len(s) - start - 1 # end postition
        
        temp = s[start]        
        s[start] = s[end]        
        s[end] = temp
        
        self.reverseString(s, start+1)
```

Answer (score -1):

This'll pass, since it has to be done [in-place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm):

```
from typing import List

class Solution:
    def reverseString(self, s: List[str]) -> None:
        """
        Do not return anything, modify s in-place instead.
        """

        left, right = 0, len(s) - 1
        while left < right:
            s[left], s[right] = s[right], s[left]
            left, right = left + 1, right - 1
```

---

### References

- For additional details, please see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-string/discuss) where you can find plenty of well-explained accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) including low-complexity algorithms and asymptotic [runtime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup>.

Comment: Compared to `s.reverse()` I wouldn't call this "simply" :-P

Comment: Yeah, the good old days when LeetCode was still about interviews...

Comment: That isnt a recursive solution, which is what they are asking for

Comment: Python strings are immutable, so the problem becomes impossible.  This code will fail if it is passed a `str`.

Comment: @MarkRansom It's not passed a `str`, it's passed a list of single-character `str`s.

Comment: @superbrain sorry, I thought `List[str]` meant you were given a list of strings that each needed to be reversed.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
chars=list('string')
for i in range((len(chars)-len(chars)%2)//2):
    chars[i], chars[-i-1]=chars[-i-1], chars[i]
print(chars)
print(''.join(chars))
```